# SSIS Parsing non standard flat file with ssis

Tags: ssis

I am new in SSIS so sorry but not find answear on internet.
I wiould like to parse non standard flat file with ssis.
The format of the the file is :

```
PiF#123
V4.6
451487#2503##311#1.67##03/04/18#04/04/18 14:38:00#14#2#1
42075#2503##180#1.65##04/04/18#04/04/18 14:52:00#14#0#0
*
4499234#2503#1#1.639999985694885#05/04/18 10:53:00
4514871#2503#2#1.639999985694885#04/04/18 14:38:00
*
4207550#2503#0P2018R1190#1.649999976158142#1#04/04/18 14:52:00
4207550#2503#0P2018R1191#1.325000047683716#1#04/04/18 14:52:00
*
```

The lines from V4.6 to first * will go for table 1
the lines between first * and second * from table 2
and the lines between second * and third * for the table 3
the information "PiF#123" has to be extracted and used ..
I hope that my explanation is clear..I don't know how to do that with c"
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Write a script component.

Comment: "Mixed record file format" will be your search term(s)

Comment: Thanks you all, but I still in same situation .. i am not good in programming , and all the example I saw have not the flat file information separated by star (*) .. How Can i manage as when i reach (*) I have to change destination table ..

Comment: where does "PiF#123" extract into ?

Comment: It's not really going to be easy to explain to you if you're not good in programming.  You should hand this task to a more experienced programmer.

Comment: Hello Ven , PIF#123 is field linked to all rows , I can extract into a new table or make it repeated for each row